# Raspberry pi zero W not connected to WPA enterprise school network

Tags: wifi, pi-zero, wpa, wpa-supplicant

I have been trying to connect my Raspberry pi Zero W to the school network. So far, it seems like I have it connected since the wifi icon is in blue, and the school network has a checkmark, although it is in gray, I am still not getting any internet. I modified the wpa_supplicant network settings

```
network={
        ssid="SCHOOLID"
        mode=0
        key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
        eap=PEAP
        pairwise=CCMP TKIP
        identity="credentials"
        password="PASSWORD"
        phase1="peaplabel=0"
        phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
}
```

Have you come across a similar problem or a possible solution. This is my first time working with pi, for a school project. Thank you for any help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: you said nothing about the school's internet connectivity policy, so my first guess is that you are not allowed to connect to the internet

Comment: If that is the entire wpa_supplicant file, then you need to set the country. Could you show us the entire file, please.

Answer (score 0):

Compared with my wpa_supplicant.conf file,It seems your file miss some content.
Here is my file,it works properly for me in my PI3 and zero.

```
country=GB

ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev

update_config=1

network={
    ssid="YOUR SSID"

    psk="YOUR PSK"

    priority=6
}
```

But first. I think you can confirm whether the net is ok by your phone.

Hope it works for you.